# WordPress audio player has is different on different browsers

Tags: wordpress, html5-audio, wordpress-shortcode

Why is the WordPress audio player different on different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague but I will try and answer this.

I believe it has to do with the browser updates and settings, the internet is evolving and updates regularly so should your browser.